# Prove that $\sqrt{c-d} \ge \sqrt{c} - \sqrt{d}$ for $c \geq d \geq 0$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I'm new to math and struggle with a probably pretty easy problem. How do you prove the inequality in the titel? Here's what I got:
$$\sqrt{c-d} \geq \sqrt{c - 2 \sqrt{c} \sqrt{d} + d}=\sqrt{ ( \sqrt{c} - \sqrt{d} ) ^2 } = \sqrt c - \sqrt d$$

But I fail to understand the jump from $\sqrt{c - 2 \sqrt{c} \sqrt{d} + d} \ $ to $\sqrt{c-d}$

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If $c,d\geq 0$, then $-2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{d}\leq 0$, so we certainly have $$c-d\geq c-d-2\sqrt{c}\sqrt{d}$$

Comment: @Dave What has this to do with the question?

Answer (score 4):

You might easier show

- $\sqrt{c-d} + \sqrt{d} \ge \sqrt{c}$

This is quickly done by squaring:

$$\left(\sqrt{c-d} + \sqrt{d}\right)^2 = c-d + d +2\sqrt{c-d}\sqrt{d} \geq c$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Squaring the given inequality we get
$$-2d\geq -2\sqrt{cd}$$

Answer (score 0):

$c-d=(√c-√d)(√c+√d) \ge (√c-√d)(√c-√d);$

$c-d \ge (√c-√d)^2;$

$\sqrt{c-d} \ge √c-√d.$

Note: $√c+√d > √c-√d >0.$

hence

$(√c-√d)(√c+√d) >$

$(√c-√d)(√c-√d)$.